# TypeError: fromisoformat: argument must be str

Tags: python, django, database, model

I have accidentally made '1' the default value for the models.DateField().
Now Django throws an error everytime I try to migrate, even if I delete the CharacterField / change the default value using (default=datetime.now()).

Is there a way to fix this?

```
Applying mainApp.0006_test_date...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 130, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 108, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 394, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 237, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field),
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 423, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 925, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1438, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1433, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1389, in to_python
    parsed = parse_date(value)
  File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 74, in parse_date
    return datetime.date.fromisoformat(value)
TypeError: fromisoformat: argument must be str
```

Comment: UPDATE:
I deleted the 0007 in the migrations folder and changed the default value in the 0006 migration. Then I ran makemigrations again and it worked. I didn't destroy my Database :D

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the 0006_*****.py migration in the dirs **apps/app/migrations** if it is the last one, and recreate the migration after change the default value in your field by using command `makemigrations`

If it is not the last one, you have to remove all next after 0006_***, change the default value of your DateField and recreate migrations by using command `makemigrations`. In this case, you probably need to destroy your db and recreate it for preventing other problems

Answer (score 1):

You have to change every '1' in your database to a correct value.

You can try something like
UPDATE <table> SET <column>='2022-01-01' WHERE <column> LIKE '1';

You can open your database with the following command (on linux) :

> sqlite3 db.sqlite3

> UPDATE <table> SET <column>='2022-01-01' WHERE <column> LIKE '1';

It may also work with cmd :

> sqlite3

> .open db.sqlite3

> UPDATE <table> SET <column>='2022-01-01' WHERE <column> LIKE '1';